# Good books on Augmented Reality on Android platform?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Can anyone suggest good books on Augmented Reality on Android platform. I am working on developing an application based on AR, I have implemented camera, compass and orientation functionality. But I am stuck on how to display set of latitude and longitudes on device's screen which I am receiving from server.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this one in web with good reviews:

Name: **Pro Android Augmented Reality**

Author: **Raghav Sood**

Link:  http://www.apress.com/9781430239451

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your suggestion. I am having this name on my list. Actually I am confused between two books. One is Professional Augmented Reality Browsers for Smartphones (Wrox Publication) and second is the one suggested by you. I am able to see the contents of book by Wrox Publication, but I am not able to get what are the contents inside the Apress one. That's why not able to finalise which one to get.

Comment: Actually I want to read about how to place set of latitudes and longitudes on small circle which is my radar on top right side of screen. Second is how to display that set of lat/lon on screen when user moves device on particular direction.

Do you know whether this topics are explained in the book you have specified? 

Thanks for your help. It is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think  there are two good books 
1 Pro Android Augmented Reality
http://www.apress.com/9781430239451
In this book you can learn about using AndAR and using other android platform based technologies

2 Professional Augmented Reality Browsers for Smartphones
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Augmented-Reality-Browsers-Smartphones/dp/1119992818](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119992818)
This book will teach you how to program AR browsers

Comment: thanks for your kind reply...
It is still not available at my place...It will be available in two weeks or so...I will personally check contents of books and take whichever suites my need...thanks...

Answer (score 0):

it depends what your looking for. Pro android Augmented Reality. I believe is more of an introduction and therefore the title should be changed. It does have some useful material. I think if you want a gentle introduction this book is very good. If you want to build something very complex or more browser orientated maybe try the book on Reality Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are exactly need is the implementation of drawing lat long values on camera surface.i suggest you to go through an open source code [Mixare](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/) ,check my any [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208268/1206201).