# Android augmented reality app convert List location from Point of Screen

Tags: java, android, math, augmented-reality, projection

I have a problem and I can't find a solution.

I have made an Android augmented reality app. In my app I have a list of points of interest, every point of interest as a location(longitude, latitude, altitude).

I know my position and I have the azimuth (of camera).

Now my question is: how can I draw those points (gps points) on the screen(x, y points)?

Comment: i think if you feel ans to be helpful to solve your problem you should Accept it as ans so that others can also be benefited.

Comment: @giucris How you solve this ?

Answer (score 5):

i couldn't got what you are exactly trying do draw,but i assume you are trying to draw those poi on camera screen something like this:[image]. For that you have to use sensors and gps location it's a little tricky,i will suggest to look at [Mixare](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/GettingStarted),you can get complete code there and tutorial [here](http://www.bango29.com/go/blog/2010/mixare-augmented-reality-tutorial).Proceed to what you are trying to achieve.Gud luck.

Comment: you've already looked at but is twisted.
for GPS and sensors I've done everything. I miss just as "skim" the elements to draw. in short, how to choose those that can be designed and how to draw

Comment: it's hard to understanding exactly where you are stuck.if you go through code i suggested,"choose to draw "and "how to draw " will be clear to you,ask exact problm you face.

Comment: my problem is how to choose which element of the List of points draw on screen, and how to convert latitude and longitude in x,y screen position

Comment: you can filter response at the time of request to api,for example only  railway stations.And to draw points go through code in mixare's mixview class.

Comment: yes, but I want create my ARengine. without the use of other framework

Comment: it's good to see you want to create your own,i am suggesting to go through the code to see how location values are drawn on camera surface...gud luck